# Generate Provisioning Certificate for iOS on windows 7

Tags: android, iphone, cordova

I already have created a phonegap application. Now, i want to build Phonegap iOS on windows 7.

I have written code in Android in Eclipse on windows 7.

I already have generated .APK, .XAP, .IPK. Now, i want to create .IPA(iOS application).

Is it compulsory to have a MAC OS to just generate Phonegap iOS application?

Is it compulsory to have apple developer account to just generate Phonegap iOS application?

Can i generate a certificate and a provisioning profile for iOS on Windows 7?

Comment: Yes, it is compulsory to have a MAC OS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is compulsory to have a Developer account, Because without developer you cannot generate Provisioning profile.

I don't know about the certificate, but you can generate Provisioning profile on Windows 7 because it is not dependent upon OS, it needs the certificate.

It is not necessary to have MAC OS for generating Phone iOS Application

Comment: Can you please explain me that how can i generate Provisioning profile on Windows 7??

Comment: Do you have the certificate with you ?

Comment: Nope, i don't have certificate yet because i don't have MAC....Is it required to create provisioning profile??

Answer (score 1):

Since PhoneGap Build uses Apple's standard development process to build applications, you will need to sign up for their developer program to build iOS applications on PhoneGap Build. You will also need a Mac to configure your certificate and provisioning profile.

Comment: Thanks Buddy. Do you know how to generate a certificate for Blackberry Application??

Comment: Man you should mark my answer as correct..no i haven't worked on blackberry.

Answer (score 1):

Compulsory to have a mac and developer account to install software on an iphone or ipad.

You don't need a mac to develop the application

Comment: Okie...got it...Do you know how to generate a certificate for Blackberry Application??

Comment: Nopes , I don't know for BlackBerry. Btw you Didn't marked my answer as correct. :(